# Multiple database requests with one php function

Tags: php, sql, function, pdo

I have a website in which I am pretty regularly referencing my mySQL Database...

In a couple instances I have one large block of php code that need to be applied to multiple database requests.

I have tried:

```
$result1 = $db->query($sql1);
$result2 = $db->query($sql2);

function action() {
  ...code...
}

foreach($result1 as $row) {
   action();
}

foreach($result2 as $row) {
   action();
}
```

With this code the `action()` function will execute; however, the sql request will not be applied to the code.

I also tried placing the `$row` variable inside the action function - `action($row)` - but that did not work either.

An answer to this problem would be great in helping me conserve time and code while progressing further with my project.

Comment: The term "sql database" is ambiguous at best.  Please specify your database engine.

Comment: And also consider adding the code for your `action` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course , the `$row` variable doesn't exist **in** the function.
You need to pass it as a parameter.

```
function action($row) {
  ...code...
//Do something with $row
}

foreach($result1 as $row) {
   action($row);
}

foreach($result2 as $row) {
   action($row);
}
```

Comment: I must have been doing something wrong the first time I tried that... That works well though, thanks.